# 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll, when trying to authenicate using Google API

Tags: c#, calendar, oauth-2.0, google-api-dotnet-client, aggregateexception

I'm trying to make a little calendar app, just for myself, using Google Calendar API. I'm using C# and .NET for this. Basically, all I did was copy the example code from [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate)
and added FileDataStore class from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.DotNet4/Apis/Util/Store/FileDataStore.cs)
Created a project in Google Developers Console, enabled API for the calendar, installed the libraries via NuGet, and all that.
So my code looks like this now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Google;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;

namespace calendar
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "here's my client id",
                ClientSecret = "and the secret",
            },
            new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
            "user",
            System.Threading.CancellationToken.None).Result;

        // Create the service.
        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Calendar API Sample",
        });
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
}
```

But when I'm trying to build it - it crashes with 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll on the first(UserCredential credential =...) line. Specifically:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Falied to load file or assembly(originally:Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку) "Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop, Version=1.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" or one of the dependencies. Couldn't find specified file(originally:либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.)
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

It's probably something easy to fix, and I guess I overlooked something, but I have no idea what it is. Can you tell me, what to do, or where in the documentation should I look?

UPD: Fixed it myself:
all I had to do was update Microsoft.Bcl.Async via command "Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async -Version 1.0.166-beta -Pre" in NuGet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that you already solved it yourself, but anyway you have more documentation on it in the following thread: [ASP.net app crashes - Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057052/asp-net-app-crashes-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-threading-tasks/21343949#21343949)